# sphinx and multilanguage search || search by attribute

Tags: full-text-search, sphinx

I'm trying to get results from sphinx by attr_string. Here is sphinx configuration:

```
source db
{-
    type            = mysql
    sql_query       = \
        SELECT id,language,text,page_url \
        FROM content
    sql_attr_string                 = language
    sql_attr_string                 = page_url

}
index content
{
    source          = db
    charset_type    = utf-8
    min_word_len    = 3
}
```

The results that i'm getting are like this:

```
[matches] => Array
        (
            [106] => Array
                (
                    [weight] => 4
                    [attrs] => Array
                        (
                            [page_url] => en/example.gtml
                            [language] => en
                        )

                )
```

What I want to do is to filter all results by "language"=en.
$sphinx->[SetFilter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sphinxclient.setfilter.php)()  is working by integers where in this case I'll need only string "en". 
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution... 
If anybody need it.

Configure "source" to use crc32, Ex:

```
source db
{
    type            = mysql
    sql_query       = \
        SELECT id,crc32(language) as language,text,page_url \
        FROM content
    sql_attr_uint                   = language
    sql_attr_string                 = page_url
}
```

And in client, modify setFilter method to use crc32(). ex:

```
$s->SetFilter('language',array(crc32('en')));
$result = $s->query('bird is a word','content');
```

I hope it helps somebody...

more information: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#attributes

Comment: You should accept your own answer. You wont get any points (and wont be penalized either!) but it marks the thread as answered.

Comment: Ah, didnt know that. Sorry for doubting you!

Comment: actually i'm thinking to delete this... I'm not glad with this workaround :S

Comment: Rather than delete, it would be better to just add another answer. This answer might still help others. Even if crc trick doesnt work for you, it might work for others.